# Recursively call "parent" constructors in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I am working on a webapp that has something like a class hierarchy created through prototype-based inheritance. We're constantly adding features to a common ancestor "class" so its constructor signature is constantly expanding.

Each time we change the ancestor's signature, we'll also have to propagate the changes to thedescendants' constructors. This is obviously a maintainability problem, so I created a function that extracts the arguments for the parent from the `arguments` object and calls the parent using `Function.apply()`.

The code looks like this:

```
BaseClass.prototype._super = function(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, this.constructor.length);
    this.parentConstructor.apply(this, args);
};
```

and used like this:

```
function Child(child_arg1, child_arg2 /*, implicit parent args */) {
    this._super(arguments);
}
```

(I can't use `arguments.caller.arguments` because the code is strict mode.
`this.parentConstructor` is set by the function building the class hierarchy.)

Unfortunately, this only works for one level of inheritance: for example, if A's parent class B has its own parent class C, when B calls `_super`, `this.parentConstructor` still points at B which means B will end up calling itself in an infinite loop.

If I store the parentConstructor field with the constructor Functions objects (instead of in the prototypes), I'll have to pass in the current calling function. This will make the line calling super tightly coupled to the surrounding function, which I am trying to avoid.

Thus does anyone know any better ways?

Comment: What do you mean with "super tightly coupled to the surrounding function"? Calling `this._super(Child, arguments)` from the `Child` constructor should be no problem, is it?

Comment: I just want to be able to copy and paste the same line of code into all child constructors without having to change it. Just like what I can do in Java...

Answer (score 0):

I asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588907/call-prototypes-overridden-method-which-then-calls-the-next-prototypes-overrid/10589514#10589514) a couple days ago and [Kamyar Nazeri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10589514/134014) helped me a lot.

The way to avoid your problem is to define `_super` in a closure where the new constructor is defined so that it always references the correct parent object. The following pattern has worked very well for me:

```
var BaseClass = 
{
   create: function() // Basically a constructor
   {
      var obj = Object.create({});

      obj.someProperty = "initial value based on arguments";

      return obj;
   };
};

var Child = (function buildChild(){
   var obj    = BaseClass.create("some value", "another argument")
     , _super = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

   // override BaseClass.create()
   obj.create = function()
   {
      var obj = _super.create.apply(this, arguments);

      // Child specific initializations go here

      return obj;
   };

   return obj;
})(); // note that this gets called right away

var c = Child.create("some argument", "another thing");

console.log(BaseClass.isPrototypeOf(c)); // true
```

Note that for older browsers you will need to provide [shims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)) for `Object.create()` and `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. I've found [this ECMAScript 5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) to be helpful. I typically only pull out the shims that I'm using.

Comment: Unfortunately this is something I've been trying to avoid. I don't like the idea of constructing an object using a function. It makes the jsdoc quite awkward and confuses poor Eclipse...

Comment: Then I think your only option is to use the actual names of the parent prototype. Why does the _idea_ of using a function to construct an object bug you?

Comment: I think this way of programming is quite inexplicit and confusing, not only to humans, but also documentation generators and optimising compilers. Also, by programming this way, none of the "class" objects are real classes, so the `instanceof` operator and many other tools won't work.

Comment: I think the issue is that JavaScript isn't really a class based language, it's a prototypal language. `new` and `instanceof` seem like crutches put in to satisfy people who aren't used to prototypal languages. `BaseClass.isPrototypeOf(c)` works as a nice replacement for `instanceof`. As I've thought about this more, I think that emulating `_super` doesn't really provide any real advantages. I think it's better to just use the real name of the object whose method you want to call. That way closures aren't necessary which may help with compiler optimizations. But I'm not expert in that area.